# How to pass list of email ids to next VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputcheckboxes

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Professional__c" extensions="sendemail" recordSetVar="Plist">
 <apex:pageMessages >


</apex:pageMessages>


    <apex:form id="frm" target="blank">



          <apex:pageBlock > 
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >  
                <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!send}" />  
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>                

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Professional's List" id="pbs">


                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Plist}" var="pro" id="pbt">

                    <apex:column headerValue="Name" >

                            <apex:outputText value="{!pro.name}" />                                              

                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Owner">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!pro.CreatedBy.name}" />
                    </apex:column>


                    <apex:column headerValue="Contact Number">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!pro.Contact_Number__c}" />
                    </apex:column>


                    <apex:column headerValue="  D_B_Company">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!pro.D_B_Company__c}" id="comp" />
                    </apex:column>


           <apex:column headerValue="Date Of Birth">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!pro.DOB__c}" id="dob" />
                    </apex:column>

         <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!pro.Email_Id__c}" id="email"/>
                    </apex:column>

                     <apex:column headerValue="Select">

                       <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selected}" >  
                       <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!sendemail}" >
                           <apex:param id="id" name="emailid" value="{!pro.name}" assignTo="{!addresses}"/>
                       </apex:actionSupport>
                       </apex:inputCheckbox>                      
                    </apex:column>




       </apex:pageBlockTable>


            </apex:pageBlockSection>



         </apex:pageBlock>   






    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class sendemail {



    public PageReference sendemail() {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();



         String[] toAddresses = new String[] {addresses};



        // Sets the paramaters of the email

        email.setSubject( subject );

        email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );

        email.setPlainTextBody( body );



        // Sends the email

        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r =

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});  



        return null;

    }

public Boolean selected {get; set;}
public string subject{get; set;}
public string toAddresses{get; set;}
public string addresses{get; set;}
public string body{get;set;}
    public sendemail() {
        //String u=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

       //addresses= addresses+';';
       system.debug(addresses);
    }




    public sendemail(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

    }
    public PageReference send() {


    return new pagereference('/apex/professionalemail');
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?  What's the exact problem?  What isn't working?  What part doesn't make sense to you?  Please provide a bit more information so people can help you.

Comment: i am trying to pass the mail ids of those records which are being selected(checkbox) how to pass all those mail ids is my question?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to pass parameters between pages is to add them to the page URL.

The Apex [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm) class provides help for this and makes sure that data added is correctly escaped. For this case you just need to pick a separator character so you can pass many values. So in the first page controller:

```
public PageReference goToSecondPage() {
    String[] emails = ...;
    PageReference pr = Page.SecondPageName;
    pr.getParameters().put('emails', String.join(emails, ','));
    return pr;
}
```

and in the second page logic where you want to access the values:

```
String[] emails = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('emails').split(',');
```

Comment: String[] emails = ...; what should I add here,Should I have to add something like this ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')

Comment: @Lak_Naren I suggest you use the line I included in the answer unless that doesn't work?

Comment: Visualforce Error


System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.
Error is in expression '{!send}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page professional: Class.sendemail.send: line 83, column 1

Class.sendemail.send: line 83, column 1

Comment: I am getting this error......

Comment: @Lak_Naren Something is null that shouldn't be on line 83. You know what is on line 83 so you need to figure out how to fix it.